# How to set up multiple regression in R?

Tags: r

I don't know how to set up a multiple regression in R and run a simple OLS estimation for it.

I only get an multiple regression equation (eg. Salary = 0.3 + 0.5*age + experience + residual ) and equations for each variables (eg. age = ... ). The error term is normally distributed with mean 0 and SD 0.3

How can I run a simple OLS estimation of salary on age and compute a standard error for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one predictor, it will be an example of linear regression instead of multiple regression. In R you can do-

```
model <- lm(Salary~age, data= your_dataset)
summary(model) # will give you summary statistics such as standard error and coefficients
```